# Filter in AngularJS - text in html tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, factory

I'm not very good at filtering and wanted to write a custom filter based on the following:

I call a service that returns a JSON object with HTML String thats concatenated with another string - so the HTML is funky.

I want to get the `text1` and `text2` form the following returned HTML string:

```
<span><b>text1</b><b>text2</b>text3</span>
```

I have no control how the above is returned to me, but i just wanted to get the two values and concatenate them: `text1text2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a builtin DOM parser - or you can find a parser in your environment. See on MDN [parsing XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) and [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element). So you could do something like this:

```
var x = "<span><b>text1</b><b>text2</b>text3</span>";
var oDOM = new DOMParser().parseFromString(x, "text/xml");
var b = oDOM.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("b");
b.length // 2
b[1].innerHTML // text2
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

if you just need to strip the html tags, I think you can use the below code

```
var noHTML =  OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

For a filter implementation

```
angular.module('myNoHtmlFilterApp', [])
.filter('noHtml', function() {
  return function(input) {
input = input || '';
var out = input.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

return out;
  };
})
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i ignore `text3`?

Comment: what is your logic of getting the data from html? Is it like only specific length of characters or is it only the values in <b> tag?
Need to understand what exactly you are trying to do in order to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Based on DineSH's answer - I did something like this:

```
$scope.getTextFromHTML = function(html){
  var oDOM = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/xml");
  var b = oDOM.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("b");
  return b[0].innerHTML+b[1].innerHTML;
};
```

I have to pre-define the html string since its not on the DOM yet, like so:

```
var html = "<span><b></b><b></b></span>";
```

I will probably add a `for loop` later in case there is a string I missed, but for now, this is perfect. Thank you for all of your help!